# DB cartesian product on same table

Tags: sql, database, join, cartesian

I have a one column table with three rows as below:

col1

team1
team2
team3
team4

I want to do a self cartesian join with result as below:
team1, team2
team1, team3
team1, team4
team2, team3
team2, team4
team3, team4

Answer (score 8):

`cartesian product` is `cross join` in DB terms, you can remove rows where teams are equal in `where` clause:

```
select
    t1.col1, t2.col1
from teams as t1
    cross join teams as t2
where
    t1.col1 <> t2.col1
```

Comment: Small correction: To get the desired result specified in the question (combination rather than permutation), you need `where t1.col1 > t2.col1`. Otherwise you wouldn't get (1,1), but you'd still get both (1,2) and (2,1) when you just want HALF of the Cartesian product for all combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You can join both tables together for the intended output like this:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col1
from table t1
join table t2
on t1.col1 <> t2.col1
```